# In what order does the Gmail API return messages when calling "Users.messages: list"

Tags: google-api, gmail, gmail-api

According to the [Gmail API reference](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list), Users.messages: list "[lists] the messages in the user's mailbox". In my observation, the messages are returned in descending order by data. Is this a correct assumption?

Basically I want to be able to process a user's inbox after a couple of days without reprocessing messages I have already processed. I would do that by stopping once I stumble upon an email I have seen before. Using the history doesn't work reliable, since it is documented that history might expire within a few hours, requiring a full new sync.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you are correct. Messages are returned in descending order, with the newest one first.

You could save the `internalDate` of the newest message and list new messages with that value in the query a few days later.

**Example**

```
internalDate = 1490213949000 // Wed Mar 22 2017 21:19:09 GMT+0100 (CET)

q=after:1490213949 // 'after' takes seconds since the epoch. internalDate/1000
```

Comment: Is there any documentation from Google that confirms this statement? Because otherwise this approach involves certain risks related to usage of undocumented functionality.