# Problems with sorting emails

Tags: gmail-api

I am wresting to sort email messages which I got using this api
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list

Does anybody know how gmail api send this messages? 
Do they send messages in order? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to [Users.messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) and Execute the Try-it. You will notice that the `threadIds` of messages appear in descending order with the newest one appearing on top. Also confirmed in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42960538).